# What happens to a lookup field in leads when it gets converted to contacts?

Tags: lookup, contact, leads

I am creating a referral program within salesforce.
I have a customer object called donor referral with these fields: first, last, email, phone, Qualified status reached (checkbox)

And with that, I create 2 lookup fields for Leads and Contacts. (reason for this is my client uses both leads and contact for donors; sometimes it can be 1 of the 2).

So the question is, what happens when a lead that is related to a donor referral gets converted to a contact? Will everything stay normal?

Once a referee reaches Qualified status (gets checked) the lead/contact that referred them gets the credit.

Answer (score 0):

A Lead, once converted, will still exist as a record. The lookup field will still hold the ID for that Lead, and clicking on it will display the Lead. You can set up your page to link to the account/contact/opportunity. However, the Contact field won't be populated. If you want do that, I'd suggest a Flow or Trigger to set the appropriate Contact Id after conversion.

Comment: doesn't the user need `View and Edit Converted Leads` permission to see the converted Lead?

Comment: @cropredy If they don't have the permission, they should be bounced to the contact record, if I recall correctly. That was the old behavior in Classic anyways.

Comment: So these leads and contacts most likely wont have opps created on them anyway. this is just a way to keep track of donors.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lead.isconverted if you want to do some actions after the lead is converted
using Triggers.( just adding some info to the convo)